# Can I use a Sharkbite connector to join copper to rubber pipe?

Tags: plumbing, copper-tubing

Can I use a Sharkbite connector to connect a copper pipe to a rubber tube instead of PVC pipe?  I am trying to make an outdoor drinking fountain. I have run black flexible piping up to a copper T-joint and want to connect the two pieces.

Can I use a SharkBite connector to do this?

Comment: What kind of flexible tubing? PEX? HDPE?

Comment: Rubber tube for a drinking fountain?   Wouldn't that make the water taste bad?

Answer (score 3):

[SharkBite®](http://www.sharkbite.com/) only officially supports 4 types of pipe, according to the [FAQ](http://www.sharkbite.com/resources/faqs/fittings/)

> #### Q:  What types of pipe can SharkBite fittings be used with?
>
> A:  SharkBite fittings are certified for use with:
>
> - Copper pipe hard drawn Type K, L and M and annealed Type M not to exceed 3/8 nominal, complying with ASTM B88
> - PEX pipe complying with ASTM F 876 or CSA B137.5
> - CPVC pipe complying with ASTM D 2846 or CSA B137.6
> - PE-RT pipe complying with ASTM F 276

If you're trying to use the fittings with other types of pipe or tube, there's no guarantee that it will work.

---

If you're plumbing a drinking fountain, you'll want to make sure you use materials listed and labeled for use with potable water. "*Rubber hose*" is not a technical term, so there's no way to tell what type of pipe it actually is. So before you continue this project, you'll want to figure out exactly what type of pipe you're using, and make sure it's safe to use with drinking water.

Since this fixture is going to be outside, you also might want to consider installing a check valve somewhere on the supply plumbing. This is done to protect the rest of the water supply, to help reduce the risk of contamination.

Answer (score 0):

If it is for outdoors, then go ahead and plug it in.  If it works, then great.  If it doesn't, then take it out or release the sharkbite off the tube.

You can visit sharkbite's site and they go over the sizes and what they warranty, but I have gotten it to fit on outdoor installs of things a lot like your description.  Obviously you want to pressure test and move it around a bit to see if it holds, and obviously I would not suggest this indoors.